# After having assigned data to the ui-guid, how can I programmatically change column properties?

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I want my grid to be as versatile as possible. So in the initial phase I'm just applying data but not any options.

However, I want the user to be able to change some properties of, say, the "5th" column, at run-time (e.g. a filter's placeholder text).

How can I do this if the `gridOptions` object is composed of nothing but the `data` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `onRegisterApi` first and then access the `columnDefs` to change the values.

This is exactly what you need to do:

> ```
> $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function ( gridApi ) {
>     $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[ 5 ].filter.placeholder = "Your Text";
> };
> ```

Make sure that the `filter` object is already initiated in your `columnDefs`.